# Sign NW.Js OSX app

Tags: macos, node-webkit, sign, nw.js

I am trying to sign my OSX app with commande lines :

```
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY -i $BUNDLEID --entitlements /tmp/entitlements.child "$OUTDIRECTORY/$NAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/$NAME Helper.app"
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY -i $BUNDLEID --entitlements /tmp/entitlements.child "$OUTDIRECTORY/$NAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/$NAME Helper EH.app"
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY -i $BUNDLEID --entitlements /tmp/entitlements.child "$OUTDIRECTORY/$NAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/$NAME Helper NP.app"
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY -i $BUNDLEID --entitlements /tmp/entitlements.parent "$OUTDIRECTORY/$NAME.app"
```

The thing is that i do not find any folder named "Framewokrs" in my generated App. 
Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I can't find this files too....